# How do I break an image into 6 or 8 pieces of different shapes?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

I am working on puzzle game, where the player can select an image from iPhone photo gallery. The selected image will save in puzzle page and after 3 second wait the selected image will be broken into 6 or 8 parts of different shapes. Then player will arrange these broken parts of images to make the original image.

I am not getting idea how to break the image and merged so that player arrange the broken part. I want to break image like this below frame. I am developing this game in cocos2d.

[image]

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Does the breaking need to be random every time or can you have a large predetermined set of breaks?

Comment: no i have 3 breaking frame like above image, i want to break image in 6,7 and 8 pieces and this breaking frame will appear according to the player age.

Comment: OK. I was asking if you could have a large set of pre-made break patterns. Or if you needed the breaking to occur randomly. You would have multiple break patterns for each number of pieces you wanted.

Comment: No, i have 3 set of pre-made break patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have pre-made break patterns. All you really need to do is collect a sub-image for each one to show.

This would likely be easiest to do with a rectangle for each shape. The rectangle should encompass the entire shape. Now break the image up into these rectangles. There will be overlap. Now apply an alpha mask to each rectangle to hide everything but the shape it's encompassing.

For example some of the rectangles would look like this:

[image: ops original image with rectangles around shapes]

Then, for example, the texture for the black rectangle would be the portion of the image that is contained by the black rectangle. Then when that is masked out, only the shape portion of the image would remain.

Comment: Hi i am new in cocos2d i dont know method to break the image, will you please give some code for breaking image in pre-made break patterns so that i get idea and i start my game.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know cocos2D. The answer I gave is code agnostic.

Comment: @Anilgupta The answer given by Byte56 is exactly what you should do. To obtain these textures, have a look at the Quartz 2D API, especially [image masking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHIJEB). So basically use Quartz 2D to generate the needed textures (scale photo and mask parts) and apply them to `CCSprites` in Cocos2D.

Comment: @Byte56 I wouldn't use those rectanlges. I don't think 8 copies of full image can cause memory problem, so I'd just applied alpha mask to whole image 8 times.

Comment: @bummzack Thanks for the domain specific addition. Gajet, you wouldn't need to copy the image 8 times, once the image is loaded as a texture, you can just apply it 8 times. I assume beyond that you're saying you'd just use screen size rectangles that are alpha masked? Yep, that works too.

Comment: Presumably both approaches would work. But creating the textures by cropping out the rectangles and masking them appropriately is most likely going to be more efficient memory-wise (8 x full screen size texture is a waste, as this basically means 8 x 1024 x 1024 for a iPhone 4 with retina display).

Comment: @bummzack I agree. I can see implementing it with full screen rectangles on a first pass, since it's simpler. Then optimizing it.

Comment: Thanks you all guys, i dont know quartz 2d i started to learn, if i face any problem i will need your help. thanks ones again.

Comment: @Byte56 I used masking for breaking an image as the above mention pattern now its breaking in different pieces but now i have one issue to make the Rect of each pieces, i need to drag the broken pieces and to adjust at correct position so that i can make again actual images. To drag and put at right positing i need to make Rect but i am not getting idea how to make Rect of this irregular shape, I will be very thankful to you, any idea or code to make rect . Thanks.

Comment: @Anilgupta I recommend asking a new question about this. It'll be far to hard to answer this in the comments section. You can reference this question in you new question.

Comment: @Byte56 please if you get any idea let me know i wasted 2 week on this and i have deadline to submit this app, please for me you just try to solve it.

Comment: @Byte56 please vote my Question so that all other developer can give answer.http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31667/how-to-make-rect-of-irregular-shape-sprite