# How do I split a texture into differently shaped pieces with libgdx?

Tags: java, textures, libgdx

I want to split a texture into variously shaped pieces with libgdx, like the pieces of a puzzle game. `TextureRegion.split()` is not an option, as it splits into equally sized rectangular texture regions.

The "Similar Questions" section here is helpful (particularly this question [How do I break an image into 6 or 8 pieces of different shapes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27650/how-do-i-break-an-image-into-6-or-8-pieces-of-different-shapes)), but I'm not sure yet if it's possible to implement the solution with libgdx.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to create something like a "jigsaw" puzzle. Off the top of my head, an algorithm that might get you started is as follows.

- Begin by splitting your image into equal pieces, it seems like the `TextureRegion.split` can do this for you.
- After this, you will have some pieces that have been split. Generate a 2D array mapping each puzzle pieces position. For example:

[image]

Essentially, the top left would be your "top left" piece, and everything running across `y = 0` excluding the end points would be your "top centers".

- With your array in hand, you can map these pieces accordingly:

[image]

You should be able to come up with some logic based on your array on how each piece should be created. Then, using some texture manipulating you can punch "holes" in the texture pieces if you're trying to create a jigsaw effect.

Comment: This is a nice conceptual overview to what I thought was an *implementation* question.

Comment: @Anko The edit makes that a bit more clear, so I'll try and add a more concrete explanation regarding to what VictorB wants later today.

Comment: Hi, do you have any update on this one? Thanks.